# Mongoose $push Not Working Properly. Unable to Push into array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model which consist of an array.

```
const MyModelSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  
  username:{

        Type:String
    }

  results: [
    {
      subject: {
        Type: String,
      },
      marks: {
        Type: String,
      }
    },
  ],

 
});

module.exports = MyModel = mongoose.model(
  "mymodel",
  MyModelSchema
);
```

I am trying to push some element using findOneAndUpdate() method available in mongoose package as below.

```
     const { id, subject, marks } = req.body;

     const myModel= await MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: id },
        {
          $push: {
            results: {
              subject: subject,
              marks:marks
            },
          },
        }
      );
```

But the query is not updating the mongodb properly. Below are the results from the above query.

```
{
  
    "_id": "6009557eea7f84203c491551",
    "username":"John Doe"
    "__v": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": "60096876b4d10b1b3c6e01fb"
        },
        {
            "_id": "600968ac1188cd2338a5533f"
        }
    ]
}
```

**It is not pushing the data correctly into the table.**

Comment: Are you sure your id in req.body is matching the one in bdd ?

Comment: Yes, I also verified that by creating a dummy test api.

Comment: is the result your displaying come from the findoneandupdate function ? or come from your database ?
By default findOneAndUpdate return the "old" object (before modification), if you want it to return the modified object you have to specify the option {new: true}

 const myModel= await MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(find, set, {new: true})

Comment: I am checking on the Robo3t directly to cross check. It is only creating _id whenever I am running the API using postman,